# Filtering using two array of objects using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I have an array as shown:

```
var arrOne = [{id: 3},{id: 8},{id: 12}];
```

And another array as shown:

```
var arrTwo = [
  {id: 1, val: 'Adam'},
  {id: 3, val: 'Bailey'},
  {id: 8, val: 'Cathy'},
  {id: 12, val: 'David'},
  {id: 15, val: 'Earl'}
];
```

I want to iterate arrTwo based on arrOne, and get the val values out of arrTwo.
So the result should be:

```
var result = ['Bailey', 'cathy', 'David'];
```

Tried concatenating .map with .filter:

```
arrOne.map(arOne => arrTwo.filter(artwo => {
    if(arOne.id === artwo.id) {
      return artwo.val
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}));
```

But it gives me all, and where it is false it adds false there, which I don't want.
Any ideas where I am going wrong will be appreciated.

Editing as per norbitrial's answer:

```
const arrOne = [{id: 3},{id: 8},{id: 12}];
const arrTwo = [
                 {id: 1, val: 'Adam'}, 
                 {id: 3, val: 'Bailey'}, 
                 {id: 8,    val: 'Cathy'}, 
                 {id: 12, val: 'David'}, 
                 {id: 15, val: 'Earl'}
               ];

const result = arrOne.map(({id}) => arrTwo.find(e => {
  const someCond = someConditionaEval();
  if(someCond && e.id === id) {
     return e;
  } else {
     return false;
  }
}).val); //this breaks
```

Comment: `arrOne.map(o => arrTwo.find(t => t.id === o.id));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) combination:

```js
const arrOne = [{id: 3},{id: 8},{id: 12}];
const arrTwo = [{id: 1, val: 'Adam'}, {id: 3, val: 'Bailey'}, {id: 8, val: 'Cathy'}, {id: 12, val: 'David'}, {id: 15, val: 'Earl'}];

const result = arrOne.map(({id}) => arrTwo.find(e => e.id === id).val);

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and if I have to add some additional checks here?:
   
    if(e.id === id && someCheck1 && someCheck2) {return e} else {return false}

Comment: @MichaelPhilips Depends but most likely you can include into `.find()` condition.

Comment: My problem is that I have to add some if() conditions inside 'e => e.id === id', and if I do that, how do I do .val in the end? because to add if inside I'll have to add parenthesis, like 
.find(e => {
   const someCond = someCondEvaluator();
   if(someCond && e.id === id) {
      return e
   } else { return false }
}.val   //.val will not work here

Comment: @MichaelPhilips That's a short version what I made in my answer, but you can use like a function block as the following: `.find(e => { if (e.id === id) { /* your code */ } else { /* your code */ } })` but for sure you need return boolean type for `.find()`. I hope that clarifies!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method on `arrTwo` and then using [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method get the filtered objects from `arrTwo` and then finally using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) get only the `val` property values from each filtered object like:

```js
var arrOne = [{id: 3},{id: 8},{id: 12}];
var arrTwo = [{id:1,val:"Adam"},{id:3,val:"Bailey"},{id:8,val:"Cathy"},{id:12,val:"David"},{id:15,val:"Earl"}];
             
var result = arrTwo.filter(a => arrOne.map(o=>o.id).includes(a.id)).map(o=>o.val)
console.log( result )
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Map of `val` by `id` from `arrTwo`, and then map `arrOne`, and extract the `val` from the Map using the `id`.

Why I prefer creating a Map/dictionary (object) instead of using `Array.map()` with `Array.find()`?

Because of the complexity - `Array.map()` with `Array.find()`, for example, is O(n * m), while creating a Map and then using `Array.map()` to get the values is O(n + m). However, if you've got two small arrays, this shouldn't actually hurt actual performance.

```js
const arrOne = [{id: 3},{id: 8},{id: 12}];
const arrTwo = [{id: 1, val: 'Adam'}, {id: 3, val: 'Bailey'}, {id: 8, val: 'Cathy'}, {id: 12, val: 'David'}, {id: 15, val: 'Earl'}];

const valById = new Map(arrTwo.map(({ id, val }) => [id, val]));

const result = arrOne.map(o => valById.get(o.id));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object with the values and then map the wanted values.

```js
var arrOne = [{ id: 3 }, { id: 8 }, { id: 12 }],
    arrTwo = [{ id: 1, val: 'Adam' }, { id: 3, val: 'Bailey' }, { id: 8, val: 'Cathy' }, { id: 12, val: 'David' }, { id: 15, val: 'Earl' }],
    values = arrTwo.reduce((r, { id, val }) => (r[id] = val, r), {}),
    result = arrOne.map(({ id }) => values[id]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Build an object from arrTwo to gather val's in one iteration.
2. use `map` on arrOne and get val from above object.

```js
const update = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const all = Object.fromEntries(arr2.map(({ id, val }) => [id, val]));
  return arr1.map(({ id }) => all[id]);
};

var arrOne = [{ id: 3 }, { id: 8 }, { id: 12 }];

var arrTwo = [
  { id: 1, val: "Adam" },
  { id: 3, val: "Bailey" },
  { id: 8, val: "Cathy" },
  { id: 12, val: "David" },
  { id: 15, val: "Earl" }
];

console.log(update(arrOne, arrTwo));
```